# If $F(x)=\int_0^x\sqrt{(1-t^2)(2-t^2)}dt$. find $F'(x) \text{ and } F''(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

If $F(x)=\int_0^x\sqrt{(1-t^2)(2-t^2)}dt$. find $F'(x) \text{ and } F''(x)$
The way I understood it in class when my professor did an example is that I have to find the derivative of both sides (that is F(x) and the stuff inside the integral) then I have integrate the integral with respect to t and that gives me $F'(x)$. But I tried this and it does not seem right at all, what is the method to solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the problem is asking you to differentiate both sides with respect to $x$.

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, 
$$\frac{d}{\,dx} \int_0^x f(t) \,dt = f(x)$$
So, with $f(t) = \sqrt{(1-t^2)(2-t^2)}$
$$F'(x) = \sqrt{(1-x^2)(2-x^2)}$$.

You can find $F''$ from here by standard techniques.

Note if we replace the $x$ in $\int_0^x$ with something like $x^2$, we will need to use the chain rule.

For example: $$\frac{d}{\,dx} \int_0^{x^2} e^{t^2} \,dt = e^{(x^2)^2}\cdot \frac{d}{\,dx}x^2$$

Comment: when I did it I got $F'(x)=\sqrt{(1-x^2)(2-x^2)}-\sqrt{2}$ because I used the bounds $F(x)-F(0)$ from the integral, why is this incorrect?

Comment: Ah, $F(0)$ is a constant so it vanishes when you take the derivative.

Comment: Now, if you replaced the lower bound with some sort of expression involving an $x$, then you would get nontrivial contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Let, $f(t)=\sqrt{(1-t^2)(2-t^2)}$ and $g$ be an anti-derivative, i.e, $g'(t)=f(t)$.

Then, $F(x)=g(x)-g(0) \Rightarrow F'(x)=g'(x)=f(x)=\sqrt{(1-x^2)(2-x^2)}$

So, $F''(x)=f'(x)$